# How can call a class function as same as the main file? (AttributeError)

Tags: python, class

I have 2 .py extensions called `main.py` and `my_class.py`.

**main.py:**

```
def foo():
    import my_class
    if my_class.my_inside_func(param) == "True":
        print("congratulations")
```

in `my_class.py` I can call the class like this:
`my_class.my_inside_func(param)`

In `main.py` I cannot call it like that. The error I get is this:

> AttributeError: module my_class has no attribute my_inside_func

I have difficulty understanding what that means.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is why naming conventions exist. You're confusing yourself because your *module* has the same name as your *class*. The class should be named `MyClass`.

Comment: The easiest way to fix it is call `my_class.my_class.my_inside_func(param)` or alternatively, change your import to `from my_class import my_class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import my_class` will import the module instead of the class inside it. To import the class inside it use `from <module> import <class>` since your module and class name is the same, you could do as below

```
from my_class import my_class
```

Hope this solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
    from my_class import my_class
    if my_class.my_inside_func(param) == "True":
        print("congratulations")
```

Answer (score 0):

Enough information isn't provided. But if the `my_class.py` is like this:

```
class my_class:
    @staticmethod
    def my_inside_func():
        pass
```

Then you should be doing `my_class.my_class.my_inside_func(param)` instead of `my_class.my_inside_func(param)` inside `main.py`.